# Qt запись/чтение байтов в файл

Tags: c++, qt, файлы

Мне надо повторить байт-код из языка Java. Если скомпилировать Java и открыть .class файл в кодировке UTF-8 - то можно увидеть следующие:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут есть как обычный текст, так и байты. Я смог такое повторить, у меня получилось вот так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только вот проблема, как теперь читать файл. Надо же как-то отличать байты от текста.
На данный момент я получаю следующие в консоль: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ожидаемый результат:

```
Hello world!
1
```

Вот сам код:

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    QFile file("myFile.bin");
    QTextStream tsfile(&file);
    QDataStream dsfile(&file);
    tsfile.setCodec("UTF-8");


    if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    {
        dsfile << QString("Hello world!\n").toUtf8();
        dsfile << 1;
        file.close();
    }
    
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        std::cout << tsfile.readAll().toStdString();
        file.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А как Вы думаете, чем отличаются "обычный текст" и байты?:)

Comment: @KoVadim байты это числа, а текст это массив символов. Я знаю что символы это просто числа. Но как мне отличить реальное число(байт), от символа

Comment: в общем случае никак. Вполне может быть, что в файле хранятся числа, но они выглядят как какой то текст. Но при этом все совпадения случайны. Но никто не мешает посмотреть на число как на код символа и если оно может таким быть, значит скорее всего это оно и есть. Утилита strings  в линуксе/gnu так и работает. Но по хорошему, нужно смотреть формат  файла и разделять его на кусочки.

Comment: @KoVadim а как тогда байт-код Java работает? М?

Comment: Если правильно понимаю, JVM разбирает файл, выделяет инструкции и выполняет их..

Comment: виртуальная машина знает формат class файла и знает, с какого байта начать.  Можно собственно посмотреть, как оно там устроено https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html